# Avoiding object mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working with React and ES6. So I arrivied to the following case: I have an state with an array of objects suppose `a = [{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2}]` in the state of `Object A`, then I pass the list to `Object B` by props, `Object B` (in the constructor) copy the list to its own state and call a function which is using `map` function where I return `b = [{id: 1, value: 1, text: 'foo'}, {id: 2, value: 2, text: 'foo'}]` (added `(text, value)` to each object), so it though it was not mutating `a` in `Object A` but it was.

So I made some tests:

```
const a = [{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2}] // suppose it is in object A

addText = (list) => {
    return list.map((item) => {item.text = "foo"; return item})
}

const b = addText(a) // suppose it is in object B
```

so under my assumption `a !== b`, but `a` was mutated by `addText`, so they were equal.

In a large scale project programmers make mistakes (I did here!) how it is supposed to be handled this kind of situations to avoid mutating objects in this way? (The example tries to represet `a` as an `state` for `Object A` which is a component from React)

Comment: You could deep copy the list so that new list does not have references to old list.

Comment: Deep clone implementation http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Comment: FWIW: I would not expect a copy when I call a function named `addText`. And imho that's part of the problem. You even write _"added (text, value) to each object"_. That is mutation. Therefore it's hard to understand when you conclude _"so it though it was not mutating".

Comment: @zeroflagL I concluded that because I was mutating inside `Object B` and I supposed it was outside the scope of `Object A`, but sure you're right, that's why I said "programmers make mistakes" I did that one, so I wanted to know how to avoid this behavior for other programmers.

Comment: There is a great quote: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." My point was, that if the function was named e.g. "createClonesWithText" chances are that you wouldn't have made that mistake. And to be honest: `map` implies returning a new value. So I don't expect this very mistake to come up often. The only way to definitely prevent the mistake is to make the objects in `a` immutable. A more sensible solution would be to pass a copy to `addText` in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your change to the object is really that shallow (at the top level of the object), you can use `Object.assign({}, oldObj, newObj)`, or if you have the [Object spread proposal](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) enabled in babel, `{ ...oldObj, newThing: 'thing' }`

To enforce this on a team, you could use this ESLint plugin https://github.com/jhusain/eslint-plugin-immutable with the `no-mutation` rule enabled.

Comment: Thank you, I ended using `Object.assign()` but is it possible to force all programmers in a team using it to prevent mutations?

Comment: Added a suggestion for that to the answer.

Comment: I added the ESLint plugin to the project but I have problems with `CustomComponent.propTypes` ESLint is linting "No object mutation allowed", but it is a React's thing, any idea about applying this linter on React projects?

Comment: You could always disable the rule on each propTypes declaration. Or check out the source of the plugin and add a an option to ignore propTypes mutations.

Comment: you could also check out redux-immutable-state-invariant here https://github.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant (it's middleware for development use, and it enforces immutability)

Answer (score 0):

By directly referring to `item.text` you are changing it.

Map iterates over an array. Since your array has objects, unlike primitive values, it doesn't duplicate them in the function scope. Instead, it *passes by reference*.

The solution is to return new (duplicated) object values whilst iterating in the `map` function.

```
const a = [{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2}]

addText = (list) => {
    return list.map((item) => {
        return {
            ...item,
            text: 'foo',
        };
    })
}

const b = addText(a)
```

You can simplify the syntax, and reduce indentation, by omitting the `return` statements as you are using arrow functions anyway.

```
const a = [{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2}]

addText = list => list.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    text: 'foo',
}));

const b = addText(a)
```