# For loop only gives the last value of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop

I've been trying to transpose a matrix (-like 2D array) in ES6 but the for loop only gives the last value of the original array and I have no idea what I did wrong.

Suppose the size of the spectrum array is 128 x 128:

```js
const width = 128;
const height = 128;

var spectrum: Complex[][] = fft(data);

// Transpose spectrum array
var transposedData: Complex[][] = new Array(height).fill(new Array(width));
for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        const c = spectrum[x][y].deepCopy();
        transposedData[y][x] = c;
    }
}

spectrum = transposedData;
console.log(spectrum);
```

This gives me a 2D array, every element of which is the value of spectrum[127][127].
What have I done wrong?

Comment: `const c` inside of a loop feels incorrect.... interesting you are using `var` elsewhere.  Probably should be `let`, and `let c` _outside_ of the loop.

Comment: Need to find the dupe of fill().... you are filling every row with the same array...

Comment: I'm guessing `deepCopy` is not doing what you think it is, and you are experiencing object mutation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416863/avoiding-object-mutation

Comment: Has nothing to do with var and copying

Comment: `deepCopy` returns a new Complex object using the same values of the original Complex object, like `deepCopy() {return new Complex(this.real, this.imag)}`. Does this seem to provoke object mutation?

Comment: has nothing to do with copying.... (going to be a broken record)

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the dupe but when you are using fill() it is not making a new array for every index, it is using the same array.

Your code is basically this under the hood

```js
    var myArr = new Array(3);
    var row = new Array(3);
    myArr[0] = row;
    myArr[1] = row;
    myArr[2] = row;
    myArr[0][0] = 1;
    console.log(myArr[0][0], myArr[1][0], myArr[2][0])
```

So when you change an index, it changes all of the indexes for all the arrays. There is no way to get fill to make a new instance of the array so you have to do some coding.

You will need to use map() to get different arrays. Since map only works with defined values you will have to fill it with something first.

```js
var foo = new Array(3).fill(null).map(() => new Array(3))
foo[0][0] = 1
console.log(foo)
```

Comment: I fixed my code according to your answer and now the script works like a charm :) Thank you very much!